# PHP executable in VS Code. Not getting it

Tags: php

I have searched and found some answers. I am not getting it. Finally downloaded and installed xampp and here is where I am:

**The errors:**

[PHP executable is not set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILYbP.png)

**The solution:**
[What I pulled for xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4L3g.png)

**My path:**
[From Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfjWi.png)

**The code I added:**
[File > Preferences > Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODncb.png)

It seems like it would work based on what I read. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The example in this VS code PHP documentation uses forward slashes https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php#_windows Not sure if that makes a difference or not, though

Comment: Based on many of the comments here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/251 it looks like it does make a difference. Try changing that.